# MySql select from subquery slow (even though subquery on it's own is fast)

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I'm trying to speed up this query:

```
SELECT order.id
    FROM (
     SELECT o.id 
     FROM `order` as `o` 
     INNER JOIN order_item as oi on
        oi.order_id = o.id
        AND `o`.`canceled` = 0
        AND ( `o`.`return_date` > "2011-03-14" OR oi.checked = 0 OR '2011-03-14' < oi.last_update)
    ) as `order`
```

It clocks at  0.0930 seconds. The subquery (SELECT * FROM `order` as `o`...) on it's own clocks at 0.0005 seconds. The table I'm testing on has about 10000 rows, 43 rows are returned from subqueries where-clause.

Except from speeding up the query, I'd really like it if someone could explain to me why the query becomes more than 100 times slower when I wrap it within another query?

MySql explain tells me that the subquery on it's own first selects `o`, and then `oi`. MySql explain for the whole query first selects  (what is derived2?), then `o` and `oi` in that order.

I'd like the subquery to be a subquery because I'm doing a lot of joins which aren't in the where clause (which I've excluded from the code and the benchmarks). If I'd use the subquery on it's own, with the joins, the query would be even slower.

Any help would be much appreciated. I've searched for answers but can't find them, and that might just be because I do not know what to look for, if so, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MySQL` buffers the inline view before doing any operations on it.

`0.0006` seconds you see for the first query is most probably the response time (the first row fetched), not the overall time (the last row fetched).

If `id` is a `PRIMARY KEY` on your `order` table, you don't need a `GROUP BY` on it.

If you have lots of items per order (more than about `20` items per order in average or so), you can try creating the following indexes:

```
order_item (order_id, checked)
order_item (order_id, last_update)
```

and splitting your correlated subquery in two:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    order o
WHERE   o.canceled = 0
        AND
        (
        o.return_date > '2011-03-14'
        OR
        (
        SELECT  MIN(checked)
        FROM    order_item oi
        WHERE   order_id = o.id
        ) = 0
        OR
        (
        SELECT  MAX(last_update)
        FROM    order_item oi
        WHERE   oi.order_id = o.id
        ) > '2011-03-14'
        )
```

Again, this will only help if you have lots of orders per items, otherwise a single scan on all orders will be more efficient.

Comment: I've changed the query as you can see a bit (this new way is quicker), but your answer is really helpful. I've been pulling my hair out because I was thinking wrapping the subquery made it very slow, even though it probably is, as you said, that the subquery on it's own seemed quicker because the response time was only for the first row. Thank you for helping me understand this! I think I need to keep the 'group by' as I'm doing joins and group_concats which I've excluded from the example (and benchmarks).

Answer (score 0):

1. check indexes
2. did you optimize tables that you are working with ?
3. query will work faster if you'll change "*" in the SELECT statement to actual names of columns that you need.
4. do you need multiple GROUP BY "order id" - one inside another?

Comment: 1. What should I look for? I've looked into it but could not come up with any improvements. 2. MySql said it could not optmize the tables, it did recreate them. Unfortunately, it did not help. 3. I select the fields 'manually', I've just simplified the query while working with this problem.

Comment: 1. "order" needs to have index on "id" and "order_item" - on "order_id"

Comment: 1. (I'm using MySql workbench). Order.id has two indexes, types PRIMARY and UNIQUE and order_item.order_id has a index type INDEX.

Comment: also try to remove "WHERE 1", it may improve time a bit.

Comment: please see 4. Try to remove 1st and 2nd "GROUP BY", and leave just last one.

Comment: 4. Removing the group bys did improve some, we're down at 0.1157 seconds. But I still can't really understand why wrappting the subquery makes the query more than 100 times slower!